# Allowing imap ports on gcp instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, smtp, firewall

I am trying to run my OsTicket instance and I want to connect to my gmail account from the server using IMAP. I noticed that that 465 and 587 are closed when I port scan using nmap or nc. I created a firewall rule to allow these ports, tagged my instance with it, and I made sure selinux is off along with firewalld turned off. Can anyone suggest anything else I should check? Or would they mind looking at the picture of my firewall rule and let me know if there's anything wrong with it.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOm6D.png)

Comment: Why are you checking for port 465 and 587? Those are outgoing (egress) ports to Gmail. You want all outbound ports open. You do not need to open incoming (ingress) ports to use Gmail. Delete your smtp rule. You will also need to enable "Less Secure Apps" on your Gmail account. https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps

Comment: In regarding for your inquire, I would suggest looking at this documentations on [sending email from an instance][1] and [checking Gmail through other email platforms][2] as it will provide the information you need.

Furthermore, when using standard email ports; By default, Compute Engine allows outbound connections on all ports but port 25, which is blocked because of the risk of abuse. All other ports are open, including ports 587 and 465.


  [1]: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/tutorials/sending-mail
  [2]: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en